# jQuery AJAX get request - cannot see returned data

Tags: jquery

I think I am missing something obvious here, but I can't figure it out.  I expect the following HTML to alert a response from the server.  But, the alert is empty.  I can see in Wireshark that the expected response is coming back to me from the server.  Why is it not populated in the data variable?

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $.get("http://www.geocommunicator.gov/TownshipGeocoder/TownshipGeocoder.asmx/GetTRS",
        {'Lat': 41,
         'Lon': -93,             
         'Units': 'eDD',
         'Datum': ''},      
        function(data) {
            alert('data:'+data);
        });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does your page also reside under www.geocommunicator.gov?

Comment: No, it does not.  The accepted answer explained my problem.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cross site protection.

You'll need to use jsonp.